# non-interactively upload file to sftp server, using password

Tags: bash, sftp

I know, this is not the recommended way to do this. But, I do not have another choice:

I've got to set up a cron job that will regularly upload a file to an external SFTP Server (no FTP available, and I do only have a username/password for it **but no key**.)

Still, I need to set up a cron that will regularly connect to that sftp and upload a file.

```
sftp <<EOF
put filename
exit
EOF
```

therefore will not work, because sftp asks for the password, before STDIN is evaluated.

What can I do, to pass the Password to sftp?

Again: I am aware of the potential security risk, but I really do not have any choice here, and the server from which the file is uploaded is protected rather well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable to a custom program that prints out the password on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/):

```
curl -u user:password -T file.tar sftp://example.com/home/user/
```